# Echo Error message in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, error-handling

```
#Note: If you see # in front of any line it means that itâ€™s a comment line not the actual code
#** ********************************************************************
FILE_NAME=filename_4.zip
FILE_LOCATION=/home/testvis/generic
ENTITY_LIST=ALL

if ${JAVACMD} -classpath $CLASSPATH:$LIB oracle.ucm.idcws.client.UploadTool \
--url=https://URL_XX/idcws/GenericSoapPort  \
then
echo “File Successfully Uploaded”
else
echo “Exception Uploaded ”
exit 0
fi
```

This is returning the echo section correctly. But  i want the error message which we get in the exception also should be echoed.

Like in PLSQL we have `SQLERRM`. Do we have a similar variable or any method in shell script ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use stderr redirection :

command-name 2> stderr.txt

or redirect all of the output like this :

command1 > everything.txt 2>&1

Example:

```
if ${JAVACMD} -classpath $CLASSPATH:$LIB oracle.ucm.idcws.client.UploadTool \
--url=https://URL_XX/idcws/GenericSoapPort  \
then
echo “File Successfully Uploaded”
else
echo “Exception Uploaded ”
echo $($COMMAND> everything.txt 2>&1)
exit 0
fi
```